# Why is this object now showing anything?

Tags: php, oop, object, inheritance

Well here's a simple parent and child class, can anyone please explain to me why's this not echoing total_pages? I've passes the value and everything..

One other thing(unrelated question), what's the need to pass parameters to child when I'm already passing them in parent's constructor? Doesn't inheritance mean all the values will be derived from parent..?

Thankyou.

```
 class Book{
    protected $total_pages;
    protected $page_type;

    function set_data($total_pages, $page_type){
        $this->total_pages = $total_pages;
        $this->page_type = $page_type;
    }
}

class Final_look extends Book{
    function preview_book(){
        echo $this->total_pages;
    }
}


$Book = new Book;
$Book->set_data(110, "thick");

$Final_look = new Final_look;
$Final_look->preview_book();
```

Comment: As an answer already says, you're creating two different objects here. Your `$Final_look` variable is already a child object from the `Book` class (and therefore, it has all its properties). You just need to create the `Final_look` object, which class is already an **extension** of the `Book` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created 2 different objects! The 2 objects have nothing to do together, they are completely independently from each other!

I think what you want is something like this:

```
<?php

    class Book{
        protected $total_pages;
        protected $page_type;

        function set_data($total_pages, $page_type){
            $this->total_pages = $total_pages;
            $this->page_type = $page_type;
        }
    }

    class Final_look extends Book{
        function preview_book(){
            echo $this->total_pages;
        }
    }


    $Book = new Final_look;
              //^^^^^^^^^^ create Object from 'Final_look' so you can use all functions
    $Book->set_data(110, "thick");
    $Book->preview_book();
         //^^^^^^^^^^^^ Same object which calls this function

?>
```

Output:

```
110
```

Comment: Well I want to access parent properties or methods from child class, that's all. Not child from parent object

Comment: @sami7913 ^ That's a contradiction if you want to access a parent property from the parent class then you access from the child a property from the parent class! I think you are a bit confused about OOP and inheritance

Comment: Looks like you don't get it yet. If you create a `Book` class (parent class in this case) and then another class that **extends** that `Book` class (let's say, **RedBook**), when you create a `RedBook` object, you are creating a `Book` with extra methods and properties (which means, `RedBook` **is a** `Book`, but a `Book` is not necessarily a `RedBook`). In other words, that `RedBook` will keep all properties of the original `Book` class plus some new you define in the `RedBook` class (let's say, ehem... the red color or any other you want and define in the **child** class).

Comment: @AlejandroIván Should that comment be for me or for OP? if it should be for OP don't forget `@username` that he gets a notification!

Comment: It was for the OP! Sorry! @sami7913

Comment: Why doesn't the final_book object have access to the property total_pages from Book? I'm simple unable to access parent current properties. isnt that the whole point of inheritance, be able to access parent properties and methods?

Comment: @sami7913 Yes, but you have 2 different Objects! Just a simple example: A class is a plan, now if you create an object you copy this plan! Now you have an exact copy. But you make 2 copies and you try from the first copy to access something which is on the second copy, which will not work!

Comment: @sami7913 You're mixing two different things here, class inheritance and concrete objects. To make it short, *no* an object created from a child-class does not share data with an object created from that child-class' parent-class. But this is actually too much to explain in these comments. You'll have to read a proper introduction to oop inheritance. Maybe start with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29).